# MySQL - Display all records, but sum only the top N records

Tags: mysql

I can't really find anything that fits my particular scenario, so I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere.

I have two tables (below with relevant columns shown):

**Category**

```
|===============================|
| ID  | Name   | lft | rgt |....|
|===============================|
|  6  | Book   |  3  |  6  |....|
|  10 | Poster |  7  |  12 |....|
|===============================|
```

**Response**

```
|=======================================================|
| ID   | CatId | Points | Status    | Calculated Points |
|=======================================================|
|  14  |   6   |   10   | Approved  |         10        |
|  32  |   6   |   10   | Approved  |         10        |
|  14  |   6   |    0   | Denied    |         15        |
|  32  |   10  |    0   | Denied    |         10        |
|  14  |   10  |    0   | Submitted |         20        |
|  32  |   10  |   20   | Approved  |         20        |
|=======================================================|
```

Right now I'm summing all response points for a given category. Here is the current SQL statement that does that:

`SELECT category.id, category.name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN response.status 
         IN ("Approved, "Denied") 
         THEN response.points 
         ELSE response.calculated_points) AS 'Points' 
FROM category 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM response)
ON category.id IN (SELECT tmpCategory.id 
                   FROM categories AS tmpCategory 
                   WHERE tmpCategory.lft >= category.lft 
                   AND tmpCategory.rgt <= category.rgt)`

In some of the categories I need to limit the summing of points to the top {N} records.

Can this be done in pure SQL or will I have to do this in my application's code?

Comment: I think you want to use "limit".

Comment: Some of the categories mean that those are specific categories IDs? Because you can use conditionals in SQL queries

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide some example structure of your tables and/or input and what are you aiming at, the question is a little unclear. Also the [php] and [codeigniter] tags have nothing to do with your question as you are asking "Without running multiple queries" which implies that you are looking for SQL solution.

Comment: `UNION ALL` maybe? `SELECT \`ip_address\` FROM \`ci_sessions\` UNION ALL SELECT SUM(\`last_activity\`) FROM \`ci_sessions\` WHERE \`last_activity\` <= 1416312152;` This is just example, you should use your logic and data though.